# Defining variables with indirect expansion

Tags: variables, declaration, expansion

I know that I can use indirect expansion to call variables whose names are contained in other variables as follows

> VAR="test"
>
> VARNAME="VAR"
>
> echo ${!VARNAME}

However if I try to redefine a variable with this:

> VARVALUE=0
> VALUE="VARVALUE"
>
> ${!VARNAME}=${!VALUE}
>
> echo ${!VARNAME}

It doesnt work, and I get

> bash: test=0: command not found

I can see why this variable declaration fails, but I can't see how to fix it.  In searching I've only found examples calling variables with indirect expansion, but not defining them so.

edit:

After a bit more searching, I've tried

> eval "${!VARNAME}=${!VALUE}"

which throws

> bash: =0: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddling with it some more, I've managed to find a solution

> eval "$VARNAME=${!VALUE}"